Why VS2022 use WiX v3 as Visual Studio 2022 Extension
Can anyone explain why VS2022 default use WixV3 as extension instead of WixV4? The WixV3 project needs to use Wixv3.11 build tools, which is out of date and is being replaced by WixV4 and WixV5. What are correct steps If I want to create a  WixV4 project in VS2022?
Thanks
In VS2022 Extensios-manage extension tab, I used search online wix,  only WixV3 shown. I expect WixV4 displayed as first choice, because VS2022's .NTE framework are 4.7,4.8, 6.0 and 8.0. I tried to install Wixv3.11.2 toolset(run wix311.exe) , error message "WIX Toolset requires .NET Framework 3.5.1 Windows feature to be enabled". I really don't want to go back so far.

For WiX v4 the VS2022 extension is named HeatWave for VS2022. By installing this extension you will get the choice to create v4 (and v5) projects as well as upgrade v3 projects.
The WiX documentation also gives a step by step guide to convert from v3 to v4 including the necessary installation steps. See WiX documentation.

Great. Just a few steps, I have updated my WixV311 to V4.Thanks a lot

@scaler is exactly correct as to the "what".
The "why" is that WiX v4 adopts Sdk-style MSBuild projects. The acquisition path for Sdk-style projects is far more streamlined than the alternatives. However, they require a completely different way of interfacing with Visual Studio.
The WiX v3 Visual Studio extension was designed for Visual Studio 2010. Honestly, it's amazing that it works at all in VS2022 given that no one actively works on it. But that design was not going to support Sdk-style projects.
FireGiant developed HeatWave, a Visual Studio extension, to support Sdk-style projects, including WiX v4, WiX v5, and versions into the future.

This is the clarifying answer I was looking for.  Thank you, Rob!

Great, would you please mark the question answered?

Hi, Rob.  I am not sure how, and don't immediately see a way to do that.  I'm not the originator of the question.  Is that something the originator can do and others cannot?  If I can do it, please advise how.  (I up-voted this answer already if that is what you were wondering about.)

My bad, I thought you were the OP, @V.Wheeler.
